# Test Runner class does not log anything

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

When I run my test with Maven command, these logs are not printed out.
Could you explain why?

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features= "src/test/resources/features/dhlcj", glue="com.dhl.gaqcjqa.fsApi.steps")

public class TestRunnerFsApi extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

static {
    Log.info("--------------------------------------------");
    Log.info("S T A R T ");
    UrlFactory.loadAllResources();
    Log.info("E N D ");
    Log.info("--------------------------------------------");
    int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    Log.info("CPU cores: " + processors);
    Log.info("--------------------------------------------");
}

}
```

Instead I get some unnecessary info like:

```
[2020-06-25 21:59:18] [INFO] Loaded: environments/dev  >> 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue that I have found in your code is you are using both Junit as well as testng in your runner. Please remove the @Runwith(Cucumber.class) in order to use only testNG. I do not know which dependency you are using for the logging in your project but the following dependency I have used in order to log the messages.

**Maven Dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Cucumber Runner:**

```
@CucumberOptions(eatures = { "src/test/resources/features" }, glue = { "com.github.frostyaxe.cucumber.stepdefs" } )

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestRunner.class);
static {
    log.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(new PatternLayout()));
    log.info("--------------------------------------------");
    log.info("S T A R T ");
    log.info("E N D ");
    log.info("--------------------------------------------");
    int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    log.info("CPU cores: " + processors);
    log.info("--------------------------------------------");
}
```

**Output:**

```
--------------------------------------------
S T A R T 
E N D 
--------------------------------------------
CPU cores: 8
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Tnx for the answer. Could you plz have a look at the pic I uploaded to see where is the issue now? some other lines are getting printed which are nor necessary.

Comment: Could you please share the updated code of runner class.